# How can I use a specific folder on my host as the home folder for the primary user of my Debian VM guest in virt-manager

Tags: debian, virt-manager, virtio

I have a Debian host running virt-manager. Once a VM is up and running, I know how to create a filesystem share to share `host:/home/user` with `vm:/blah`.

What I want to do is make it so `vm:/home/person` is `host:/home/user`. Ideally I'd like to do this during the installation of the Debian VM.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this?

I feel like that, somehow, during the Debian VM installation, I'd need to tell the installer to mount `host:/home/user` as `vm:/home/person`. Is that possible?

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. You may end up with software running concurrently on the host and the VM accessing the same files (like setting/cache databases, conf files).

Comment: Not possible. `/home/user` on `host` is not a user that will ever log into `host`.